# Laravel 5.4 - Validation with Regex

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

**Below is my rule for project name:**

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    'projectName' => 'required|regex:/(^([a-zA-z]+)(\d+)?$)/u',
];
```

I am trying to add the rule such that it must start with a **letter from `a-z` or `A-z` and can end with numbers but most not.**

Valid values for project name:

```
myproject123
myproject
MyProject
```

Invalid values for project name:

```
123myproject
!myproject
myproject 123
my project
my project123
```

I tried my regex online:

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/FylFY1/2

It should work, but I can pass the validation even with `project 123`.

*UPDATE*: It actually works, I just tested it in the wrong controller, im sorry... but maybe it will help others nevertheless

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Your rule is well done **BUT** you need to know, specify validation rules with regex separated by pipeline **can lead** to undesired behavior.

The proper way to define a validation rule should be:

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    'projectName' => 
        array(
            'required',
            'regex:/(^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)?$)/u'
        )
]);
```

You can read on the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex):

> regex:pattern
>
> The field under validation must match the given regular expression.
>
> Note: When using the regex / not_regex patterns, it **may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters**, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

Comment: ups. my variant actually works too, I just tested it on the wrong controller :/

Comment: With Laravel 5.5+ you can invoke $request->validate(['field1'=>'required|regex:/foo/u']);`.

Comment: have you miss brace ')'