# Laravel validation by extension

Tags: laravel, validation, logging

need help to validate my form input
i need user only able to upload file with extension .log

so far i've tried as the code shown below but the validator still reject the input even the file is .log

thanks in advance

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
            [
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'file_log' => 'mimes:text/plain,log'
            ],
            [
                'email.email' => 'Please input valid email address',
                'file_log.mimes' => 'Mohon hanya mengunggah file yang berekstensi .log ',
            ]
        );
```

Comment: A file extension is not a mime type. `'file_log' => 'mimes:text/plain,log'`. You should use a regex validation to validate the filename ends in `.log`

Comment: thanks sir, can u give me an example about the regex implementation based on my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42577289/320487

Comment: thank you ..your link bring me to a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 - Validation with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577045/laravel-5-4-validation-with-regex)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this :

```
            'file_log' => 'mimes:text/x-log '
```

another way

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  [
     'file'      => $request->file,
     'extension' => strtolower($request->file>getClientOriginalExtension()),
  ],

  [
     'file'          => 'required',
     'extension'      =>'required|in:log',
  ]
);
```

Comment: i upload file that i crete using notepad file.log the result still  >>>The file log must be a file of type: text/x-log .

Comment: u can check if the file extension is .log or not

Comment: check my edited code and edit if any thing change is needed

Answer (score 0):

ok finally i find an answer
thanks for your answer

```
// Create custom validation rule
Validator::extend('logfile', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
$regexPattern = '/\.log$/';
$filename = $value->getClientOriginalName();
return preg_match($regexPattern, $filename);
});


    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'file_log' => 'logfile',
        ],
        [
            'email.email' => 'Please input valid email address',
            'file_log.logfile' => 'Please upload only file .log',
        ]
    );
```