# Laravel regex format string php

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I need validate textarea with this data:

```
string:data
string:data
string:google
```

I need allow only this format string in textarea. Allow break and one string with other with delimiter: ":".

I validate with:

```
$request->validate([
   'textarea' => 'required|string|regex:/:/'
]);
```

But this is not working. How I can fix it?
I need rule for my situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 - Validation with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577045/laravel-5-4-validation-with-regex)

Comment: No. This is not my question!!!

Comment: try this: `textarea' => 'required|regex:/^\w+:\w+$/gm'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$request->validate([
   'textarea' => 'required|string|regex:/(.)+:(.)+/'
]);
```

Or if you need only "data" or "google" after the colon:

```
$request->validate([
   'textarea' => ['required','string','regex:/(.)+:(google|data)+/']
]);
```

PS note on the second you have to use an array if your regex has a pipe operator `|` [(documentation)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-regex)

> Note: When using the regex / not_regex patterns, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.