# Need Regex for Matching in Mysql based on search parameter where character are arabic

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Lets say the words in tables are :

- ab astest
- ab astestabc
- ab as
- ablxyx pqr tpl
- ab as ablmnr
- wasab as ablmnr
- vbn ab as abltere

I need to match where the starting word should be : "ab as" ( Including space ) and then infinity ( that is n no. of combinations or characters )

The result should look under 2 filters :

1) Include space : Starting with "ab as" and any no. of words or characters attached

Result :

---

ab as ablxyx pqr tpl

ab as ablmnr

2) Exclude space : Starting with "ab as" and any no. of characters and words attached to this string without space

Result :

---

ab astest

ab astestabc

The results should be mutually exclusive.

Can anyone share me the Mysql REGEX expression for the same?

Comment: Where's the Arabic?  Is the title wrong?  What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP for that

> ```
> CREATE TABLE textlist
>     (`text` varchar(17))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO textlist
>     (`text`)
> VALUES
>     ('ab astest'),
>     ('ab astestabc'),
>     ('ab as'),
>     ('ablxyx pqr tpl'),
>     ('ab as ablmnr'),
>     ('wasab as ablmnr'),
>     ('vbn ab as abltere')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(`text`,POSITION("ab as" IN `text`),LENGTH(`text`)) 
> FROM textlist WHERE `text` REGEXP 'ab as[[:blank:]]';
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTR(`text`,POSITION("ab as" IN `text`),LENGTH(`text`)) |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------- |
> | ab as ablmnr                                              |
> | ab as abltere                                             |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(`text`,POSITION("ab as" IN `text`),LENGTH(`text`)) 
> FROM textlist WHERE `text` REGEXP 'ab as[^[:blank:]]';
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTR(`text`,POSITION("ab as" IN `text`),LENGTH(`text`)) |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------- |
> | ab astest                                                 |
> | ab astestabc                                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7b1ace9bc52509e1e845533977716ef)*

Comment: How do we convert above mysql query into Laravel 5.4 eloquent ?
Any help.

Comment: Please accept my answer and ask a new Question with laravel tag, and use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577045/laravel-5-4-validation-with-regex  as starting point for your search the rest you will find in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-regex.