# Laravel 8: How to validate entering dimensions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a form and there is a field in this form called `dimensions` and users MUST enter a value like this: `10x10x10`

So I am separating length, width and height by `x`.

But now I don't know how to make this validation with Laravel:

```
$request->validate([
     'dimensions' => 'required|max:10|min:5',
]);
```

So the question is: How can I force users to separate each dimensions by writing `x` ?

Comment: Look here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577045/laravel-5-4-validation-with-regex

Comment: You need regex for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`regex`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-regex) validation rule. You'd provide it with a `pattern` that matches your requirements (`10x10x10` in your case).

Something like the following:

```php
'dimensions' = ['required', 'regex:/^([\d]+x){2}([\d]+)$/']
```

You might want to constrain the number of digits it allows to prevent daft input. The `+` after `[\d]` is greedy and will match digits an unlimited number of times.

```php
'dimensions' = ['required', 'regex:/^([\d]{1,5}x){2}([\d]{1,5})$/']
```

The above pattern constrains the number of digits allowed the a minimum of 1 and maximum of 5 (`{1,5}`) rather than unlimited (`+`).

There is probably a neater `pattern` that someone might suggest.

Comment: No need for parentheses around last `[\d]` and imho easier to read without {n}: `regex:/^[\d]+x[\d]+x[\d]+$/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input masks.

Look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/inputmask

Then in your field you will see this:

[image]

and the user just have to enter the numbers.