# Laravel special validation for phone numbers and post code

Tags: php, laravel

I have this validation:

```
return [
            'order_name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'order_surname' => ['required', 'string'],
            'order_address' => ['required', 'string'],
            'order_city' => ['required', 'string'],
            'building_number' => ['required', 'string'],
            'order_post_code' => ['required', 'string'],
            'order_email' => ['required', 'string'],
            'order_phone' => ['required', 'string'],
            'shipping_method' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'package_type' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'package_size' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'order_sending_parcel' => ['required', 'string'],
            'order_recipient_parcel' => ['required', 'string'],
            'shipping_company' => ['required', 'string']
        ];
```

I need change my validation to:
order_post_code => XX-XXX form (string with "x" and X - is digits)
order_phone => I need form +48XXXXXXXXX (where X is digits).

How can I make it?

Comment: hi you can use regex for validation. this link can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577045/laravel-5-4-validation-with-regex

Comment: I 'm not understand regex :( Can you show me correct code?

Comment: 'phone' => 'required|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/'
This will check the input starts with 01 and is followed by 9 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
return [
    'phone' => 'required|regex:/(48)[0-9]{9}/',
    'postal_code' => 'required:regex:/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}/'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'order_phone' => 'required|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/'
```

This will check the input starts with 01 and is followed by 9 numbers.

Comment: It's not working.
I change phone number to form 9 digits. I make this code:
```
return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:250'],
            'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:250'],
            'street' => ['required', 'string', 'max:150'],
            'building_number' => ['required', 'string', 'max:250'],
            'city' => ['required', 'string', 'max:60'],
            'phone' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{9}/',
            'postal_code' => 'required:regex:/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}/',
        ];
```

and it's not working :(