# Regex for allowing Hindi Characters along with English in PHP

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I've a Laravel 5.8 Application and the application accepts both Hindi & English Text as an Input.

In order to prevent special characters, I've created a Regex Validation which allows English Characters of either case, Numbers, space and '/'.

`'title' => 'required|min:3|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-\/ ]+$/',`

Furthermore, I have updated it for allowing Hindi Texts.

`'title' => 'required|min:3|regex:/^[\u0900-\u097F]*[\s]?([\u0900-\u097F]*[\s]?)*?$/'`

This regex **`/^[\u0900-\u097F]*[\s]?([\u0900-\u097F]*[\s]?)*?$/`** does not seem to work. It does not allow Hindi Characters. For Example, I want this string to pass "गुढ़ी पाडवा/चेती चंद / उगाडी / Gudi Padwa/Cheti Chand / Ugadi"

However, this pattern **`"[A-Za-z0-9\u0900-\u097F\-\/ ]+"`** works well in html tags, blade file, but not in the controller, when intercepted via **Request**

Please suggest a valid Regex for allowing Hindi Characters along with English in PHP

Comment: It is not that `^[\u0900-\u097F]*[\s]?([\u0900-\u097F]*[\s]?)*?$` doesn't allow Devanagari characters; it is just that there is no `/` in it. If you already have a regex that works, why this question?

Comment: It works for client side, in front-end. It does not work in controller in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCRE2 doesn't support the `\uxxxx` syntax by default, according to [the docs](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC3). Its valid equivalent is `\x{xxxx}`.

That said, you can use the following:

```
[A-Za-z0-9\x{0900}-\x{097F}\-\/ ]+
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TOB9Nf/1).

Since Devanagari is a recognized script, you can also use the Unicode property syntax: `\p{Devanagari}`.

```
[A-Za-z0-9\p{Devanagari}\-\/ ]+
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TOB9Nf/1).

Comment: Note that in PHP, the regex should be used with the `u` modifier (e.g. `/regex/u`) to enable UTF-8 mode.

Comment: @InSync It still doesn't work. The dash - in [A-Za-z0-9\x{0900}-\x{097F}\-\/ ]+. 
ERR: range out of order in character class at offset 20. Escaping the  '-' does not match the input.

Comment: @HVSharma The regex on its own should match. I'm not entirely sure, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42577045) is the problem.

Comment: Olivier s hint and your answer helped. Thanks @InSync.
I tried ChatGPT and it's answer "regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9ऀ-ॿ।॥\/\-\.\s]+$/u" also worked.